# vue.jsでtodoリストを作っていますが、編集機能をつけたい。

Tags: javascript, vue.js

#### 解決したいこと

vue.jsでtodoアプリを作っていますが、作成したtodoを編集できるようにしたいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

いろいろなことを試しました。現在はエラーは出ませんが、変更も反映されません。

#### 頭の中で考えている編集機能実装処理の流れ

①アイコンを押すと、editTaskアクションが発生する。
②プロンプトが出てきて１文字以上入力すると、実引数の中にidと入力した文章を入れて、edit関数に移行する。
③editindexを定義して、もしeditTaskアクションのidとedit関数のidが同じ（つまり、どのtodoを編集したかの確認）だったら編集後の文章をeditindexに代入。
④仮引数のtitleを編集後の文章（editIndex)をtodosの中に入れる。

#### 該当するソースコード

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <link
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>TODOアプリ</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Vue.jsでTODOアプリ</h1>
      <form v-on:submit.prevent="addTasks">
        <label for="title">タイトル</label>
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          name="title"
          placeholder="タスクを入力してください。"
          size="30"
          maxlength="20"
          v-model="addTitle"
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="deadline">期限</label>
        <br />
        <input type="date" id="deadline" name="deadline" v-model="deadline" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="追加する" />
      </form>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ステータス</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>タイトル</th>
            <th>期限</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(todo, index) in todos" v-bind:key="todo.id">
            <td><button @click="changeToDo(todo.id)">作業完了</button></td>
            <td>{{todo.id}}</td>
            <td>{{todo.title}}</td>
            <td>{{todo.deadline}}</td>
            <td @click="removeTask"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
            <td @click="editTask"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr
            v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
            v-bind:key="todo.id"
            v-if="todo.flag === false"
            class="completeTasks"
          >
            <td><button @click="changeToDo(todo.id)">戻す</button></td>
            <td>{{todo.id}}</td>
            <td>{{todo.title}}</td>
            <td>{{todo.deadline}}</td>
            <td @click="removeTask"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [],
    addTitle: "",
    deadline: null,
  },
  // 一部省略　//
    editTask() {
      let newTitle = window.prompt("以下内容で更新します。");
      if (newTitle === "") {
        alert("入力欄が空欄です。");
      }
      this.edit(newTitle);
    },
    edit(title) {
      this.todos[0].addTitle = title;
    },
    // 以下省略
```

#### 自分で試したこと

試したことその１

```js
editTask() {
      let newTitle = window.prompt("以下内容で更新します。");
      if (newTitle === "") {
        alert("入力欄が空欄です。");
      }
      this.edit(newTitle);
    },

edit(title) {
      let editIndex = "";
      this.todos[editIndex].addTitle = title; 
    },
// TypeError: Cannot set property 'addTitle' of undefined と出る
```

試したことその２

```js
editTask() {
      let newTitle = window.prompt("以下内容で更新します。");
      if (newTitle === "") {
        alert("入力欄が空欄です。");
      }
      this.edit(newTitle);
    },
    edit(title) {
console.log(title) // 入力された文字が出力される
      this.todos[0].addTitle = title;
    },
```

試したことその３

```js
editTask() {
      let newTitle = window.prompt("以下内容で更新します。");
      if (newTitle === "") {
        alert("入力欄が空欄です。");
      }
      this.edit(newTitle);
    },
    edit(title) {
      let editIndex = this.todos.addTitle;
      editIndex = title;
    }, // エラーは出なかったが反映はされず。
```

試した結果を載せた結果ごちゃごちゃで醜くなってしまいました。基礎的なことかと思いますが、よろしくお願いします。
他サイトでも同様の質問してます。
https://teratail.com/questions/296016

Answer (score 1):

editの引数にindexを渡すことで解決しました。ありがとうございます。